# How to get authorization code from redirect response

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am using a Java wrapper for Spotify and I am trying to find a way to get the authorization code from the redirect URI so I can use it when requesting an access token. I am new to OAuth so any help would be great! Thanks!

I am able to copy the code from the browser redirect and hard code it into my code.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You need to be specific. In general, the whole point of the _redirect_ is that you write a Web server that receives the request the browser makes and then does something with the parameters.

Comment: I give authorization through spotify and I am redirected with the authorization code appended to the URI. I can see the code in the browser bar but I want to access it in my code.

Comment: I'd suggest you check this guide out: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/
The `code` is a QueryString parameter supplied after the initial auth needs to be exchanged in your server-side code for the access/refresh tokens. There is a recommended verification process to in this flow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the redirect_uri parameter as a Servlet url.

```
@WebServlet("your/servlet/Url")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyServlet()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //get the authorization code 
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        //get tokens and use them as per your requirement using code 
        ...
        //redirect user to the final destination
        response.sendRedirect("url");
    }
}
```